# how can i add a delay in my fade in/out of a array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a delay between the fade in and fade out of my script but i cant get it to work. can someone help me?

```
(function animate() {     
  $("#quotes").fadeOut(500, function() {
    index = (index + 1) % quotes.length;
    this.textContent = quotes[index];
  }).fadeIn(500, animate);
})();
```

Comment: Have you tried `.delay(interval)`? http://jsfiddle.net/zceKN/116/

Comment: thanks it worked! I didnt know you just could add it to the .fadeIn(500, animate) part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to fix the problem thanks to [satpal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533/satpal) reply:
Have you tried .delay(interval)? jsfiddle.net/zceKN/116

this is the working code now:

```
(function animate() {     
  $("#quotes").fadeOut(500, function() {
    index = (index + 1) % quotes.length;
    this.textContent = quotes[index];
  }).fadeIn(500, animate).delay(4000);
})();
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this it will work.

```
(function animate() {     
    $("#quotes").fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow', animate);
        index = (index + 1) % quotes.length;
        this.textContent = quotes[index];
    })
})();
```

Comment: it fades out like it should and then fades in again. but after the fade in it changes the qoutes. instead of changing when it faded out

Comment: i was able to fix it with a .delay()
anyway thanks for helping!
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467710/7636356](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467710/7636356)